# pandas .shape doesn't work

Tags: pandas, shapes

In results_merged.ipynb [file link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pAGAE_Q8uFKTjA_TC0wuMeqMajTRyC61) I can’t figure out why .shape works in

“In [32]: 
df.shape

but not in 
“In [42]:

```
groupmodel = df.groupby('model')
groupmodel.shape
```

The only thing I see as relevant is that df and groupmodel are both dataframes, so .shape should work on both of them.

Thanks very much.
If anyone is willing to answer 15 other questions, here they are: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FIOexhH_8cr_WsXtIjQ-Snmj0p1L9VUqmmgAu5UVuSI/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=115573317562990243595

Comment: a `groupby` object is just metadata describing how to perform the `groupby` it isn't a `DataFrame` or `Series` as such as so `.shape` has no meaning here until you perform some aggregation on the object or other method such as `head()` which will then return a `DataFrame` or `Series`

Comment: Also don't post a link to 15 questions, it's 1 problem per question. Most of those questions can be answered by googling or searching on SO